# Remove recursion from quicksort

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, quicksort

I have a recursive function that sorts an array of numbers:

```
function quickSort(initArray) {
    if (initArray.length <= 1) { 
        return initArray;
    } else {

        var left = [];
        var right = [];
        var newArray = [];
        var pivot = initArray.pop();
        var length = initArray.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (initArray[i] <= pivot) {
                left.push(initArray[i]);
            } else {
                right.push(initArray[i]);
            }
        }

        return newArray.concat(quickSort(left), pivot, quickSort(right));
    }
}
```

I want to remove the recursion from it so that I can follow step by step what the function returns. So I change the return to:

```
return newArray.concat(left, pivot, right);
```

Then I call this function in a loop so that I can print the array that is returned:

```
let myArray = [6, 7, 1, 5, 0, 3, 9, 8, 2, 4];
let br = false;
while(!br) {
  let newArray = quickSort(myArray);
  console.log(newArray);
  if(this.isSorted(newArray)) {
    br = true;
  }
}
```

I get this kind of result: (2 = pivot in this case)

```
[0, 4, 3, 1, 7, 5, 9, 8, 6, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 5, 9, 8, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 5, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 5, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

```js
var shuffle = [6, 7, 1, 5, 0, 3, 9, 8, 2, 4];

console.log(shuffle);
quickSort(shuffle);

function quickSort(initArray) {
    if (initArray.length <= 1) { 
        return initArray;
    } else {

        var left = [];
        var right = [];
        var newArray = [];
        var pivot = initArray.pop();
        var length = initArray.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (initArray[i] <= pivot) {
                left.push(initArray[i]);
            } else {
                right.push(initArray[i]);
            }
        }
        console.log([].concat(left, pivot, right));
        return newArray.concat(quickSort(left), pivot, quickSort(right));
    }
}
```

From an initial array `[6, 7, 1, 5, 0, 3, 9, 8, 2, 4]` and the last number as pivot I want to see:

```
[ 1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 5, 9, 8]
[ 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 9, 8]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 9, 8]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 8, 9]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original algorithm sorts `left` and `right` *before* concatenating them with `pivot`. In your modified algorithm, it concatenates an *unsorted* `left` and `right` with `pivot` (which ends up losing all information for what has and hasn't been sorted). Also, at each iteration you're calling `quickSort` on `myArray` instead of `newArray`. `myArray` is having elements popped off with each call to `quickSort`. That's why elements are disappearing and it's giving you the wrong output. If you just want to check what the status is at each iteration, you could try just taking the original algorithm and adding

```
console.log([].concat(left, pivot, right));
```

Just before the `return` statement.

Quick sort can be pretty tricky to implement without the recursion, so creating a looping version probably wouldn't make the algorithm any easier to understand.

**Edit**

The challenge with your latest snippet is that at each iteration, you only have a partial, "zoomed in" view of the whole array.  I was able to modify it to print what you want by inputting the rest of the array at each iteration just for logging purposes.

```
var shuffle = [6, 7, 1, 5, 0, 3, 9, 8, 2, 4];

console.log(shuffle);
quickSort(shuffle, [], []);

function quickSort(initArray, metaLeft, metaRight) {
    if (initArray.length <= 1) { 
        return initArray;
    } else {

        var left = [];
        var right = [];
        var newArray = [];
        var pivot = initArray.pop();
        var length = initArray.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (initArray[i] <= pivot) {
                left.push(initArray[i]);
            } else {
                right.push(initArray[i]);
            }
        }

        console.log([].concat(metaLeft, left, pivot, right, metaRight));
        var sortedLeft = quickSort(left, metaLeft, [pivot].concat(right, metaRight))
        var sortedRight = quickSort(right, metaLeft.concat(sortedLeft, pivot), metaRight)
        return newArray.concat(sortedLeft, pivot, sortedRight);
    }
}
```

`metaLeft` is everything that's to the left of the currently zoomed in frame, and `metaRight` is everything that's to the right of the currently zoomed in frame.

This prints:

```
[ 6, 7, 1, 5, 0, 3, 9, 8, 2, 4 ]
[ 1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 5, 9, 8 ]
[ 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 9, 8 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 9, 8 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 8, 9 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

Comment: With this solution I also get an array decreasing in length. I probably need to pass pivot and left / right array to my sort function...

Comment: Yes, the logged output would decrease in size at each step, because you're "zooming in" on just the previous iteration's `right` or `left`. Are you saying that the final returned value from the _original_ algorithm is smaller than its input?

Comment: I added a snippet. I get the result of each iteration (sub sections) when I want to display the whole initial array modified step by step.

Comment: Thanks for the addition!  I expanded my answer to print out the entire array at each step.

Comment: awesome! I couldn't figure this out.